# Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at localhost:3306: Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have installed MySQL at Ubuntu 18.Can open it, no problems. Trying to open workbench and but it returns me the following.

Could not open database  Please: 1 Check that mysql is running on server localhost 2 Check that mysql is running on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be changed) 3 Check the root has rights

I tried almost everything recommended in the internet. Changing to my_native_password does not work either. Who had any recent success, would be grateful!

Comment: in addition. I checked, it does run on port 3306 and on server localhost...

Comment: Check the answer of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53608064/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-x-x-x-x-on-windows